Authentication as user with a Google service to a website through Oauth2
I am writing a Go script that calls a website's API methods, and the only way to authenticate to that API is to include an Cookie header with an authentication token in the requests. The authentication token is set when the user receives the response of the Oauth2 redirect_uri callback. There is no other way to authenticate to the website except the Google Oauth2 method. Therefore I need to simulate a oauth2 consent flow in order to receive an authentication cookie from the website's API.
I tried to open the oauth2 window as a service account in my code using the golang.org/x/oauth2/google package, but it seems to just respond with the actual oauth2 window and not go through the flow automatically with the information of my service account
package main

import (
   "context"
   "encoding/json"
   "fmt"
   "io"
   "net/http"
   "os"

   "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
)

func main() {

   scope := Scope{
       Profile: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
       Email:   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
   }

   credentialsFile, _ := os.Open("my_private_key.json")

   credentials, _ := io.ReadAll(credentialsFile)

   conf, _ := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(credentials, scope.Email,  scope.Profile)

   client := conf.Client(context.Background())

   resp, _ := client.Get(getOauthWindowURL())

   fmt.Printf("%+v\n", resp)

   body, _ := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)

   page, err := os.Create("page.html")
   if err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }

   page.Write(body)
   page.Close()

   //fmt.Println(string(body))
}

func getOauthWindowURL() string {

   client := &http.Client{}

   resp, err := client.Get("oauth2/consent/URL/website_API/endpoint")
   if err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }
   defer resp.Body.Close()

   bodyJson, _ := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)

   body := AuthBody{}

   json.Unmarshal(bodyJson, &body)

   return body.AuthorizationUrl
}

type Scope struct {
   Profile string
   Email   string
}

type AuthBody struct {
   AuthorizationUrl string `json:"authorization_url"`
}

I have removed error handling to improve readability.
The workflow is as follows:

A oauth2 consent window URL is requested by the client.
The website API responds with such an URL including the redirect callback URI
The client goes through the oauth2 flow and ends up with a authentication cookie provided by the website callback.

My question is: Can I simulate going through the oauth2 consent window in an Go script using a Google Service account
